# The first final tagless approach

Tags: scala, scala-cats, tagless-final

I am trying to use the first time tagless final pattern in Scala and struggling a bit.

I have the following algebras definition:

```
trait DbSetting[F[_]] {
  def read(url: String, user: String, pw: String): F[DbParameter]
}

trait Environment[F[_]] {
  def get(v: String) : F[Option[String]]
}
```

and the interpreters implementation:

```
final case class DbParameter(url: String, user: String, pw: String)

sealed trait DbError extends NoStackTrace
case object DbSettingError extends DbError


sealed trait DbError extends NoStackTrace
case object DbSettingError extends DbError


// Environment implementation
object Environment {

  def apply[F[_]](implicit ev: Environment[F]): ev.type = ev

  def impl[F[_]: Sync]: Environment[F] = new Environment[F] {
    override def get(v: String): F[Option[String]] =
      Sync[F].delay(sys.env.get(v))
  }
}

// DbSetting implementation
class DbSystemEnvironment[F[_] : MonadError[*, Throwable]] private(env: Environment[F])
  extends DbSetting[F] {
  override def read(url: String, user: String, pw: String): F[DbParameter] = env.get(url)

}
```

What I am trying to do is, to compose `Environment` into `DbSystemEnvironment`. The problem here is, I can not get the value out of `env.get(url)` because, I do not know anything about `F` in `DbSystemEnvironment`, except it is a `MonadError`. 
How to get the value out of `env.get(url)::F[Option[String]]`?

In addition, if `env.get(url)` returns `Nothing` in `read` function, then it should return `MonadError`.

Comment: Why do you mean by "getting the value of `env.get(url)`"? You want to `.map` it, `.handle` errors or something else? Because with algebras you have defined for `F` (Sync/MonadError), you can lift value, map/flatMap it handle, mapN, etc, but not turn F[A] into A (that would require Comonad).

Comment: Tangential, but I would look at ZIO (https://zio.dev/) as an alternative to tagless final. I personally find it easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are asking how to extract the returned value from calling `env.get(url)` and then map it to a `F[DbParameter]`.

Since you have `MonadError` for your `F[_]` you should be able to map the result pretty readily by doing something like this:

```
import cats.syntax.flatMap._
import cats.syntax.applicative._
import cats.syntax.applicativeError._

override def read(url: String, user: String, pw: String): F[DbParameter] = 
  env.get(url).flatMap {
    case Some(ev) => DbParameter(ev, user, pw).pure[F]
    case None     => (new Exception("No environment parameter found!")).raiseError[F, DbParameter]
  }
```